# Proving continuity for two variable function at specific point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I cant seem to wrap my head around the method of proving continuity for a two variable function.

Given the following function $f$ such that :
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^4+y^5}{x^3+y^3} &\quad\hfill x^3+y^3\neq0\\ 0 &\quad\hfill x^3+y^3=0
\end{cases}
$$

The request is to check if $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$.

What is the general method of proving if it is continuous?

From what I've learnt, I can disprove continuity by choosing a function $y=\lambda x$ that goes through $(0,0)$ and then by placing said function in $f$, show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x,\lambda x)\neq f(0,0)$.

When it comes to proving that a function IS continuous, I'm kind of lost.

An example I've got from a classmate for a solution to this was to find $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}|f(x,y)| $  (easy to show that it's is zero by squeeze theorm, but I am uncertain that finding that limit has anything to do with the limit we're looking for.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: "the limit we're looking for" --- which limit do you think we're looking for here?

Comment: obviously, the limit we're looking for, is: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)$

I'm uncertain in which way to approach this, weather to substitute $x$ or $y$ for something, or to do some math-y trickery

Answer (score 1):

The two limits are closely related. In general we have

$$ \lim_{x \to a } f(x) = l \iff \lim_{x \to a} \vert f(x) - l \vert =0$$

This follows directly from the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of a limit since we have

$$ \vert f(x) - l \vert  = \vert \vert f(x)- l \vert - 0 \vert.$$

This should answer your question.